# pChart does not render to web browser, only shows missing image

Tags: php, html, pchart

pCharts documentation says that you should be able to render the image to the browser using this code.

mypic.php

```
$myPicture->stroke;
```

mypage.html

```
<IMG SRC=‘mypic.php‘>
```

The `img` tag is supposed to invoke the php script. Within the PHP script, the stroke function sets the `content-type: image/png`.

So here is what I have:

netsales.php

```
<?php
     include('../class/pData.class.php');
     include('../class/pDraw.class.php');
     include('../class/pImage.class.php');

     /* query sales and create new image */

     $myPicture->stroke;
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
     include ('netsales.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
     <div>
          <img src="netsales.php" />
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not getting any errors, just the red X for a missing image.

Comment: Is `stroke` not a function? So try `$myPicture->stroke();`?

Answer (score 1):

try removing the

```
<?php
     include ('netsales.php');
?>
```

From index.php, and add

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

Before the Stroke call.

Answer (score 0):

I try something like this and works:

```
//html file//////////////////////
<?php include ('my.php'); ?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div> <img src="my.php" /> </div>

</body>

</html>
///////////////////////////////////


//my.php file/////////////////////////
<?php

 /* pChart library inclusions */ 
 include("pChart/class/pData.class.php"); 
 include("pChart/class/pDraw.class.php"); 
 include("pChart/class/pImage.class.php"); 


 //...


 $myPicture->autoOutput("picture.png"); 

?>
///////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working for me I had comment include function in HTML file:

```
<?php //include ('my.php'); ?>
```